# HTML5 Plotting Library Performance Issue on MAC?

Tags: html, canvas, svg, flot, protovis

I am looking into plotting a very large data. I've tried with FLOT, FLOTR and PROTOVIS (and other JS based packages) but there is one constant problem I'm faced with.  I've tested 1600, 3000, 5000, 8000 and 10k points on a 1000w 500h graph which are rendered all within a reasonable time on PC browsers (IE and FF).  But when rendered on MACs FF/Safari, starting with 500 data points, the page becomes significantly slow and/or crashes.

Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: Do you have a sample page we could look at?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, don't do that.  It seems pretty unlikely to me that 10k points are actually going to be visible/useful to the user all at once.

You should aggregate your data (server-side) and then if they want to zoom in on areas of the data, use AJAX requests to get that area and replot.

If you use flot, they have examples showing selection, i.e. here:  http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/zooming.html

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment the Ryley answer yet, that's why I put some remarks here)

What about an offline use. Html is a great format for documents, set aside the server/client stuff.

JavaScript, Canvas and all those fancy client-side technologies could be used to build nice interactive files, like data reports containing graphs with zoom and pan features ...